# Send hyperlink via chat Facebook Messenger API

Tags: spring-boot, facebook, hyperlink, chat, facebook-messenger

I am using Facebook Messenger API, in order to connect with my spring boot application and communicate with users via chat. It will be very helpful for me to respond with text that contains hyperlink . I can have a text like : " Hello , you can use this : CLICK ME" , and click me has a link attached to that word. I tried by sending an attachment, but I do not want to send as link button, I want to send as paragraph copied from another source that can contains hyperlinks. Hopefully you can help me because I am out of ideas.